# Aggregating based on range from two columns in pandas or pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a specific problem in my project which requires computing average based on multiple columns.

As I cannot share my project data, I have posted a sample problem which has similar constraints as mine.

My data frame looks like below.

```
UserID      Start_KM    End_KM      Time_Taken(secs)
ABC         20          35          12
ABC         36          47          25
CDE         20          27          8
CDE         28          33          13
CDE         34          42          20
CDE         43          47          22
```

This data captures various time taken by users at different kilometer intervals. Now I want to plot a line graph that represents an average time taken for various time intervals. Something like this below.
[image]

I solved this problem programmatically (May be a brute force way as of now) by creating a bucket for every 5 kilometer range and dissect every row entry into these buckets and compute average.

However I feel on millions of data this may not be a scalable solution.

Can someone help me with any APIs defined in pandas or pyspark that could help me in this case simpler?

Comment: "...average time taken for various time intervals"? Do you mean average time for a route section? Please show us the code you have used to create this plot.

Comment: So I have route range buckets like 20-25, 25-30, 30-35, 35-40. For each bucket range I wanted average time taken based on the data provided above. This graph was handcrafted not via code. My expectation was to have a code for that.

Comment: Have you tried pandas.cut()?

Comment: I still dont understand if you want to bucket by time, or bucket by the KM range. You seem to be conflating the two at various points in your post: "A graph that represents an average time taken for various time intervals", "by creating a bucket for every 5 kilometer range"

Answer (score 2):

You can use function [Bucketizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.Bucketizer) from pyspark.ml.feature

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("ABC", 20, 35, 12),
                                 ("ABC", 36, 47, 25),
                                 ("CDE", 20, 27, 8 ),
                                 ("CDE", 28, 33, 13),
                                 ("CDE", 34, 42, 20),
                                 ("CDE", 43, 47, 22)],
                                ["UserID","Start_KM","End_KM","Time_Taken(secs)"])

df = df.withColumn("Time_Taken(secs)",f.col("Time_Taken(secs)").cast("double"))

bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[-float("inf"), 5., 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., float("inf")],inputCol="Time_Taken(secs)", outputCol="Time_Taken(buckets)")
bucketed = bucketizer.transform(df)
bucketed.show()
+------+--------+------+----------------+-------------------+
|UserID|Start_KM|End_KM|Time_Taken(secs)|Time_Taken(buckets)|
+------+--------+------+----------------+-------------------+
|   ABC|      20|    35|            12.0|                2.0|
|   ABC|      36|    47|            25.0|                5.0|
|   CDE|      20|    27|             8.0|                1.0|
|   CDE|      28|    33|            13.0|                2.0|
|   CDE|      34|    42|            20.0|                4.0|
|   CDE|      43|    47|            22.0|                4.0|
+------+--------+------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Then you can use the obtained column to calculate what you want.